fsolve (scipy) results in ValueError
I am solving so called Blasius problem.  I use the following code (copied from youtube lecutre https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L4h-hqZY2Y , timecode: 8:35):
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

eta = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

def blas(f, t):
    return (f[1], f[2], -(1/2)*f[2]*f[0])

def blas0(x, ts):
    f0 = (0., 0., x)
    f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
    return 1.-f[-1, 1]

print(blas0(0.0, eta))
print(blas0(0.1, eta))
print(blas0(0.2, eta))
print(blas0(0.332, eta))
print(eta)

xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta), xtol=1e-6)

All the listed print-functions work well and print correct results.  However, the function fsolve results in the following error:
xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta), xtol=1e-6)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested 
array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected 
shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.


I tried to downgrade numpy and scipy packages.
I tried to add dtype=object in definition of eta.
I tried to use the function root instead of fsolve.
I tried to use other solutions found here (or in google).

Neither of these methods work.
The packages list:
Package         Version
--------------- -----------
contourpy       1.3.0
CoolProp        6.6.0
cycler          0.12.1
fonttools       4.53.1
kiwisolver      1.4.7
matplotlib      3.9.2
numpy           2.1.1
packaging       24.1
pandas          2.2.2
pillow          10.4.0
pip             24.2
pyparsing       3.1.4
PyQt6           6.7.1
PyQt6-Qt6       6.7.2
PyQt6_sip       13.8.0
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0
pytz            2024.2
scipy           1.14.1
six             1.16.0
tzdata          2024.1


Does anybody knows what the problem can be?

Your issue is that fsolve expects an sequence for x0 and it is silently converting the a sequence when a number is passed.  And your need to pass in args as a list or tuple.
You can fix this by just pulling the first element from x in blas0
def blas0(x, ts):
    x = list(x)[0]
    f0 = (0., 0., x)
    f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
    return 1.-f[-1, 1]

Here is the full solution:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

eta = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

def blas(f, t):
    return (f[1], f[2], -(1/2)*f[2]*f[0])

def blas0(x, ts):
    x = list(x)[0]
    f0 = (0., 0., x)
    f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
    return 1.-f[-1, 1]

xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta,), xtol=1e-6)
print(xpp0)
# prints: [0.33205733]


Sorry, I do not understand.  The documentation for fsolve says that x0 should be a single number if there is a function of one argument.  If there is a function of two arguments, then x0 should be a list of two numbers etc.  In my case I have a function of only one argument, therefore x0 is a single number.

Look at the documenation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html, the x0 type is ndarray.  Regardless of number of arguments, it is expecting a list or array and is converting the input to a list when a number is passed in.

Do you mean this:  xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=[0.1, 4], args=(eta), xtol=1e-6) ?  This gives the same error.

args=(eta,).  The argument for args is supposed to be a tuple.

I tried this.  The comma after eta does not change anything.  Moreover, the source video does not contain this comma.

James,  your suggestion x = list(x)[0] results in the following error:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

One way or other you need to make sure f0 is a valid 1d numeric array..  My answer is wordier but arrives at the same conclsion.

I have inserted pirnt-function inside blas0:
print(x.shape)
f0 = (0., 0., x)
It shows, that there is no problem with arrays, actually.  The variable x in f0 is recognized as a float number, so f0 is a correct tuple of float numbers:     print(x.shape)
^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

Similar code def blas0(x, ts):
f0 = (0, 0, x)
print(x, f0, ts.shape)
f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
return 1.-f[-1, 1]

Shows that there is no problem with f0: example output when x=0.332 is
0.332 (0, 0, 0.332) (101,)

I updated my answer with the full implementation.

@HeatTransfer, interesting.  we have case of "well, it works on my machine."  Perhaps a version difference?

Here's the FULL error message
In [124]: xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta), xtol=1e-6)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[124], line 1
----> 1 xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta), xtol=1e-6)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:163, in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
     51 """
     52 Find the roots of a function.
     53 
   (...)
    153 
    154 """
    155 options = {'col_deriv': col_deriv,
    156            'xtol': xtol,
    157            'maxfev': maxfev,
   (...)
    160            'factor': factor,
    161            'diag': diag}
--> 163 res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    164 if full_output:
    165     x = res['x']

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:229, in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    227 if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    228     args = (args,)
--> 229 shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
    230 if epsfcn is None:
    231     epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:26, in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

Cell In[123], line 13, in blas0(x, ts)
     11 def blas0(x, ts):
     12     f0 = (0., 0., x)
---> 13     f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
     14     return 1.-f[-1, 1]

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_odepack_py.py:242, in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    240 t = copy(t)
    241 y0 = copy(y0)
--> 242 output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    243                          full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    244                          ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,
    245                          int(bool(tfirst)))
    246 if output[-1] < 0:
    247     warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.

Note that actual error is in the odeint call, not the fsolve itself.  All those clipped lines mislead you and your readers.
An error message like this means that some argument is a "ragged" array, something with a mix of shapes, and it can't convert it to a regular numeric array.  Searching SO for that "inhomogeneous" phrase will turn up lots of examples.  But here we need to determine which odeint argument is bad, and why.
numpy versions, and up/down grades have nothing to do with this kind of error.  Something about your code, and arguments you pass is wrong.
Using args=(eta) when it should be (eta,), a tuple looks suspicious, but doesn't fix this particular issue.

Testing blas0 calls is good, but we need to see exactly what fsolve is doing.
Adding a print line to blas0:
In [128]: def blas0(x, ts):
     ...:     f0 = (0., 0., x)
     ...:     print(x, f0, ts.shape)
     ...:     f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
     ...:     return 1.-f[-1, 1]
     ...:     

In [129]: eta.shape
Out[129]: (101,)

In [130]: blas0(0.1, eta)
0.1 (0.0, 0.0, 0.1) (101,)
Out[130]: 0.5507916014363659

Now look at the fsolve:
In [131]: xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta,), xtol=1e-6)
[0.1] (0.0, 0.0, array([0.1])) (101,)
...

f0 is a tuple containing an array.  Trying to make an array from that tuple raises your error
In [132]: np.array((0.0, 0.0, np.array([0.1])))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[132], line 1
----> 1 np.array((0.0, 0.0, np.array([0.1])))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.

changing blas0 so it treats x as a scalar, and it works
In [133]: def blas0(x, ts):
     ...:     f0 = (0., 0., x[0])
     ...:     print(x, f0, ts.shape)
     ...:     f = odeint(blas, f0, ts)
     ...:     return 1.-f[-1, 1]
     ...:     

In [134]: xpp0 = fsolve(blas0, x0=0.1, args=(eta,), xtol=1e-6)
[0.1] (0.0, 0.0, 0.1) (101,)
[0.1] (0.0, 0.0, 0.1) (101,)
[0.1] (0.0, 0.0, 0.1) (101,)
[0.1] (0.0, 0.0, 0.10000000149011612) (101,)
[0.28363035] (0.0, 0.0, 0.283630348083009) (101,)
[0.32424457] (0.0, 0.0, 0.3242445695754514) (101,)
[0.3318578] (0.0, 0.0, 0.33185780004663934) (101,)
[0.33205655] (0.0, 0.0, 0.3320565471407554) (101,)
[0.33205733] (0.0, 0.0, 0.3320573348245278) (101,)
[0.33205733] (0.0, 0.0, 0.3320573349034362) (101,)

In [135]: xpp0
Out[135]: array([0.33205733])



I have written, that print-functions work correctly.  Therefore, odeint works, because blas(x, ts) uses odeint to calculate its output.  Therefore, I conclude, that odeint is not a problem.  2.  fsolve calls odeint -- you are right.  So, the problem is that fsolve cannot vary parameters correctly and find the root.


The problem is in the f0 = (0., 0., x) line.  fsolve makes x0 into a 1d array.   Testing blas0/blas0 is a good idea, but we have to make sure we call them in the same way that the fsolve/odeint do.  The FULL traceback is still the most important diagnostic tool.

I presume, you use Jupyter to show results like this:
Cell In[132], line 1
----> 1 np.array((0.0, 0.0, np.array([0.1])))
?
I use a simple text editor and terminal only.
Nevertheless, your suggestion is similar to one James told eariler.  However, it does not work, unfortunately:
f0 = (0., 0., x[0])
~^^^
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Is this when calling blas0 directly, or via fsolve?  x[0] does not work if x is a simple number, but does it is a 1d array.
